# Duvida sobre android utilizando classes

Tags: android, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Tenho o seguinte método implementado e irei usar ele em varias Activities

```
private int dia, mes, ano;
String data;
String dd, mm;

int hora, minuto;
static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
String horas;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sub_casa_quarto);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    ano = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mes = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    dia = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    hora=c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    minuto=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if (mes >=1 && mes<10){
        mm = "0"+String.valueOf(mes);
    }
    else
        mm = String.valueOf(mes);

    if (dia>= 1 && dia<10){
        dd = "0"+String.valueOf(dia);
    }
    else
        dd = String.valueOf(dia);

    data = String.valueOf(ano) + "-" + mm + "-"+dd;
}

//Data
public void onCLickteste(View v){
    final DatePickerDialog dialogo = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDataSetListener, ano, mes, dia);
    dialogo.show();
}

private OnDateSetListener mDataSetListener = new OnDateSetListener(){

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth){
        int a = year;
        int m = monthOfYear;
        int d = dayOfMonth;
        if (m >= 1 && m<10){
            mm = "0"+String.valueOf(m);
        }else
            mm = String.valueOf(m);
        if (d>=1 && d<10){
            dd = "0" + String.valueOf(d);
        }else
            dd = String.valueOf(d);

        data = String.valueOf(ano) + "-" +mm+ "-" +dd;
        mostrarData();
    }
};

private void mostrarData(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Data Selecionada" + data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Gostaria de criar uma class e colocar ele lá para não precisar repetir o código. Alguém poderia me ajudar ou explicar como fazer isso? Preciso do retorno (resultado) para salvar no banco de dados.

Comment: Você pode utilizar `Fragments` para fazer isso. Veja este [post](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você for usar esse método somente em Activities você pode criar uma `GenericActivity extends Activity` e estender essa suas classes dela, assim o método criado (`public` ou `protected`) poderá sempre ser acessado por suas filhas. Ex.:

```
public abstract class GenericActivity extends Activity {
.
.
.
/*Mostra uma mensagem de alerta*/
protected void showNeutralDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    if (title != null) {
        builder.setTitle(title);
    }
    builder.setMessage(message);

    builder.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    builder.create().show();
}
```

E nas filhas você usará assim:

```
public class MinhaTela extends GenericActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.telaTeste);
    showNeutralDialog(MinhaTela.this, "Título", "Isso é um teste.");

 }
}
```

No exemplo ele mostra uma mensagem de alerta neutra sempre que chamamos o método e essa chamada pode ser feita de qualquer classe que estenda de `GenericActivity`.
Tente aplicar esse conceito na suas classes e generalizar seu método.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma classe que terá métodos estáticos que irão executar essas operações. Esses métodos devem receber todas as dependências necessárias para realizar a operação e retornar o tipo de dado que você espera.

Exemplo:

```
public class Util {
    public static Integer executa (int arg1, int arg3, ... , int argN)  {
       .
       .
       .

       return value;
    }    
}
```